# Can you remove a gem from gear?

Tags: diablo-iii

Let's say I have a  normal  topaz and I drop it into an item. I then find two more normal topazes (topazei?) and I want to combine them. Can I then remove the gem from that item, and if so how will it effect the gem and the item in question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the [Jeweler](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/)'s abilities. It does cost gold, however, with more gold the higher the level of gem involved.

If you're not interested in getting the item back, you can salvage an item for the same result.

[image]

Comment: When does said jewler unlock? I'm only at the very beggining of Act II.

Comment: Act II 6~7 quest

Comment: Removing a gem does not cost anything anymore. I don't remember since when though, but a [forum post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/20751615213) says it was changed around Nov. 2016

Comment: @DrFish Are you sure it is free now? I didn't manage to find a patch note mentioning it. The only thing I can come with is the [2.0.5 patch](https://us.diablo3.com/en/game/patch-notes/2-0-5) where the cost for unsocketing is lowered. Even in [this "recent" guide](https://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2018-11-01-diablo-3-ultimate-evil-guide?page=9) it is saying that the player have to pay for unsocket gems. Can't test it for now, will give it a try when back home.

Comment: In the last two seasons (17 and 18) it has been free. I played with two seasonal chars and can confirm that it's free. Might test with a non-seasonal char to be sure.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the jeweler to remove gems from sockets.

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/